# Problem extracting table from pdf from web page with tabula (Web Scraping in Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, tabulate, tabula-py

when I extract a table from a page, I manage to extract without problems, but the data is out of order. There is data from one column that appears as the title of another column for example, how can I fix this? My code:

```
from tabula import read_pdf

url='https://becas.osinergmin.gob.pe/seccion/centro_documental/hidrocarburos/SCOP/SCOP-DOCS/2022/01-Demanda-Nacional-Combustibles-Liquidos-Enero-2022.pdf'

df=read_pdf(url, pages=1)
df
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a common problem with PDF files.  The information in a PDF is designed to be printed.  It was never designed to be scraped.  The text in a PDF does not appear in the same order you read it; every string has an X,Y coordinate.  You can try using  PDFMiner or PyPDF2, but there's no guarantee any of them will be able to pull this as you expect.

Comment: Can you provide the sample output and the one you want to achieve?

Comment: @R.Marolahy You can see the output of my code in this notebook: https://github.com/abnercasallo/Tabula-Issue/blob/main/code.ipynb  . I want to achieve the dataframe according to original pdf: https://becas.osinergmin.gob.pe/seccion/centro_documental/hidrocarburos/SCOP/SCOP-DOCS/2022/01-Demanda-Nacional-Combustibles-Liquidos-Enero-2022.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: Use tabula program to find coordinates. We just need upload the program: https://tabula.technology/ and dowload the JSON file to see the coordinates. We need to put it in "area" argument of read_pdf function in this order: top(y1), left (x1) , bottom (y2) and right (x2) distance.

Now I've created a loop for all pdfs with the same coordinates and It's working well.